# Can Raspberry Pi host Node JS Applications

Tags: node.js, mongodb, raspberry-pi, raspberry-pi3, raspberry-pi4

I am building a management system in node JS for a local business . The application will have a maximum of 10 concurrent users. Most of the tasks of application are basic CRUD operations on MongoDB with minimal processing . The application might generate PDFs but in most cases for one user at a time .I was thinking of hosting it on a local server. Rather than building a proper server , is it possible that I can use a raspberry PI 2/3/4 whichever is suitable to host MongoDB and node JS application and will the PI be able to handle the load so that the application is performing.

Comment: There's no way for us to know if it can handle the load because that depends a lot upon what exactly the load is in your application.  You can run nodejs on a raspberry Pi if you can fit your app and the other components you need into the memory available.  For 3rd part components, you have make sure that if they contain any native code that they can be compiled for the specific version of ARM in your Pi.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it can, the main problem will be the storage. How will you manage to store data in a microsd card.

Comment: I've done this successfully. I used a thumbdrive in a rPi USB port for extra storage.

Comment: I only use the microsd card, i just have 8Gb data storage, shared with OS.